# When I copy a Page, its ParentalManyToManyFields aren't copied. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: wagtail

I have an `EventPage` model that defines a number of `ParentalManyToManyField`s (one for tags and one for Event Sponsors). When I copy one of these pages, the regular ForeignKey fields get copied, but the `ParentalManyToManyField`s don't.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
tags = ParentalManyToManyField('master_calendar.EventTag', blank=True)
series = models.ForeignKey(
    'master_calendar.EventSeries2',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='events',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL
)
sponsors = ParentalManyToManyField(
    'master_calendar.EventSponsor2',
    related_name='events',
    blank=True
)
```

The `series` field gets copied just fine, but `tags` and `sponsors` don't. Why might that be happening?